# How to turn a standard model class/struct into observable properties?

Tags: swift, reactivekit

I am using ReactiveKit with their Bond extension, and I can't really figure out how to do something that feels kind of basic.

Let's say I have a User model in my app. Something like this.

```swift
class User: Codable {
  var id: String
  var firstName: String?
  var avatar: String?
}
```

The content comes from a remote API, by making it confirm to Codable everything works nice and easy.

But let's also say for example that I would like a bidirectional binding from a model property to some UI state; that is not possible since none of my properties confirm to the `BindableProtocol`. Or if I want to observe changes to my model's properties, this is not possible either of course.

So my question is: how do I turn my model properties in actual observable Properties, without breaking the existing User model and behavior? For example, it still needs to be Codable. Do I make a second `ObservableUser` class, and then have didSet in all properties on the `User` model to write changes to the `ObservableUser`? And something similar on the `ObservableUser` to write changes back to the `User`? That seems horrible and hopefully not the recommenced way forward.

Comment: If switching to RxSwift or ReactiveSwift would help with this, I would also like to hear answers that include those libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create another object to make model properties observable. But there is definitely an overhead of implementing the `decoder & encoder` methods and coding keys `enum` as below which is also a standard practice in many cases,

```
class User: Codable {
    var id: String = ""
    var firstName = Observable<String?>(nil)
    var avatar = Observable<String?>(nil)

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, firstName, avatar
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        self.firstName.value = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
        self.avatar.value = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .avatar)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(self.id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(self.firstName.value, forKey: .firstName)
        try container.encode(self.avatar.value, forKey: .avatar)
    }
}
```

Now you are able to bind any `UIView` element.

---

Normally, with reactive approach, `ViewModel` is where you create `bindable` properties that provide value from your model to view and update model property by keeping the model invisible by the view.

Comment: You are correct, in the end I dropped this whole idea and am creating the bindable properties in my ViewModels. Probably a day after posting the question :)
Still, good answer, so I'll mark it as correct and grant the bounty.